# How to do python .exe file with face_recognition module

Tags: python, windows, opencv, exe, face-recognition

[image]I did programm using face_recognition module and when I try to make .exe file for Windows it doesn't work. May be smb can tell me what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the file `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` from here 
http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
and extract it and place in `C:\Users\YOUR_NAME\PycharmProjects\test_exe\dist\face_recognition_models\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`

That needed file is a trained model for Dlib!